# A better way to write object for event listener on submit button?

Tags: javascript, object, singleton, addeventlistener

I wrote a simple log in page. I want to use a javascript event listener for the submit button. My goal in this is to improve my javascript writing with making it most efficient and clean by using an object. I chose an singleton object function since there will only be one instance of this ever. This is what I have and I was wondering a better way to write the javascript portion. I only inlcuded the html portion to give an idea of is going on:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login_main.css"></link>

</head>

<body>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
    <div id="enter">Enter Username :<span class="blinkme">>_</span><input class="inputs" type="text" name="uname" maxlength="20" autofocus="autofocus"/></div>
    <div id="enter">Enter Password :<span class="blinkme">>_</span><input class="inputs" type="password" name="pword" maxlength="20"/></div>
    <div id="done"><a href="">[< Submit >]</a></div>
    </form>

</body>
            <script style="text/javascript" src="js/login_main.js"></script>
            </html>
```

localhost js # cat login_main.js

```
  var formStuff = function () {
          var variables = {
        done : document.getElementById("done"),
          }


        function getSubmit () {
            docuement.forms[0].submit();
        }

        return {
            submitForm: getSubmit,
                done: function () { return variables.done; },
        }
    }();

    window.onload = formStuff.done.addEventListener("click", formStuff.getSubmit, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put:

```
<div id="done"><a href="javascript:document.forms[0].submit()">[< Submit >]</a></div>
```

Or (but then you should remove the <a ...>):

```
document.getElementById("done").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.forms[0].submit()
}, false);
```

Comment: "document.getElementById("done").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.forms[0].submit()
}, false);".....ah....very true i guess i was making things harder than they were. I have been told before that it is better to use the even listener because the html way listed above could be exploited.